# why setup upgrade command revert back already dropped foreign key in magento 2.4.2

Tags: setup-upgrade, magento2.4.2, upgradeschema, foreign-key-constraint

I have written one custom module with a simple UpgradeSchema file to drop core foreign key (table product_alert_stock, foreign key name - PRODUCT_ALERT_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID )

[ReferenceLink](https://webkul.com/blog/delete-existing-foreign-key-magento2-installer/)

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $setup->getConnection()->dropForeignKey('product_alert_stock',
         'PRODUCT_ALERT_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID'
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

And it is working very fine ( as required dropping that foreign key constraint) as I run **setup:upgrade** command first time to install this new custom module but when the next time I run **setup:upgrade** for any other purpose, that foreign key added back to the table with same name and not being dropped again, no matter how many time I run setup upgrade.

Additionally as I checked if I delete my custom module name entry from **setup_module** table and run setup upgarde it is dropping that foreign key and on next setup upgrade adding back again. I am guessing that as it is magento's core foreign key so somehow in upgrade, magento is adding it back but as I have written UpgradeSchema without checking the module version it should run and work every time on setup upgrade. So I am not understanding why it is working only first time on fresh module install. I really need to drop this key permanently.

If anyone know or have any other way to drop this foreign key, please help me out here. I already tried google for any solution but didn't find anything. Please suggest what changes or approach should I make to get this done

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first thing first - **you are using upgrade schema approach (which is deprecated**) and you should instead **use the [declarative schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html#drop-a-foreign-key.) or [data patches approach](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html)** as the upgrade scripts will no longer be supported in the future.

If you check the https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html#drop-a-foreign-key, you will see that in order to drop a foreign key, you have to also [generate the schema whitelist file](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html#create-whitelist) which *provides a history of all tables, columns, and keys added with declarative schema. It is required to allow drop operations*.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks you so much, you just made my day. That is the real approach I was looking for.

Comment: you are most welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Diana](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35330/diana-botean) suggested that the correct approach to drop foreign key from table is to use declarative schema. So I used below db_schema.xml in my module to remove that foreign key -

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
  <table name="product_alert_stock">
   <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="PRODUCT_ALERT_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID " table="product_alert_stock" column="customer_id" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE" disabled ="true"/>
  </table>
</schema>
```

And it worked . !! Thanks [Diana Botean](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35330/diana-botean)